# How to apply the background color to buefy table?

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I have a table like this and would like to append bulma class "has-background-color-dark"

```
<b-table :data="data" :columns="columns"></b-table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just add class to your component:

```html
<b-table class="has-background-color-dark" :data="data" :columns="columns"></b-table>
```

It will apply class to the top parent element of table component:
`<div class="b-table has-background-dark">...` .
But Bulma set a white background in the `<table>`, so the whole table is not dark, just pagination.
As we can see in [the source code of buefy table component](https://buefy.org/documentation/table#api-view), there is no way to change that by attributes. So, we have to go in css with `/deep/`.
Add your own class like `<b-table class="myTable has-background-color-dark" ...` and add style bloc to your component:

```js
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.myTable {
  /deep/ table.table {
    background-color: $dark;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `class` property in your `data` option like this

```
export default {
  data() {
     return {
       tableClassList: ['some-class']
     }
  }
  computed: {
  },
  created() {
  },
  mounted() {
  },
};
```

Then in your template you bind that prop to your class attribute like this

```
<b-table :data="data" :class="tableClassList" :columns="columns"></b-table>
```

Then, let's say you want to append the `has-background-color-dark` class after an action like clicking a button. For this example user clicks a button and a method `appendClass` is called like this

```
export default {
  data() {
     return {
       tableClassList: ['some-class']
     }
  },
  methods: {
      appendClass() {
        this.tableClassList.push('has-background-color-dark')
      }
  },
  computed: {
  },
  created() {
  },
  mounted() {
  },
};
```

In this example I used an array as a list for classes. You can also use a object for more complex conditional appending. More info on class binding [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exilod/xd7zqg6s/)

Comment: Thanks heaps @Allkin. Actually it's appending the class to <div class="b-table"> instead of <table class="table has-mobile-cards"> but anyway I will try further based on your suggestion.

Comment: It will not work because bulma set background-color in table element. See my response below.